# Common potential of two capacitors in series

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, capacitance

I have read in a book that if two capacitors are connected in series then their common potential will become $$\frac{C_1 V_1-C_2 V_2}{C_1+C_2}$$ I just need to know how this happens. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Two possible errors: (1) It should be in parallel to have a common voltage, (2) your numerator should be positive sign instead of negative sign. $\frac{C_1 V_1 + C_2 V_2}{C_1 + C_2}$.

Comment: Think of it as two parallell plate capacitors in series instead represent one capacitor with a thicker dielectric.